# Engine oil in my transmission oil

Tags: transmission-fluid

Good day, they threw engine oil in my transmission oil. What should I do and can I drive it like that?

Comment: The shop that did it should do a trans flush and refill for free.

Answer (score 4):

If it is an automatic transmission, then **don't** drive it, get it changed right away. The valve systems & clutches work under very fine tolerances and are not designed for engine oil.

if it is a manual, then should be ok to drive a short distance but don't tow trailers or heavy loads and get it changed.